# How to do `git fetch` and `git merge` in remote repo, not in local, with SourceTree?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

My workflow without SourceTree is like this. I type it in command line. I have a local repo on my local machine. And I have a server with a copy of my local repo. And I use Bitbucket for my remote repo. The first part (local) I do in my local machine. Then I connect my server using SSH and type the the second part, `git fetch`, `get merge`:

```
# On local repo:
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Commit message"
$ get push origin foo-branch

# On remote repo
$ git fetch origin
$ git merge origin/foo-branch
```

I know how to do the first part local in SourceTree. But how to do the second part in SourceTree? Is it possible? Currently I do a local part in SourceTree. Then But have to switch to command line to make `git fetch` and `git merge` in my remote repo. I connect my server with SSH and type commands.

**UPD:**

How to automate an update of a server copy of my remote repo? So that it would be unnecessary to connect the server with SSH in command line and type `git fetch` and `git merge`.

For example, I just push a commit on my local machine and my server automatically fetches and merges changes.

**UPD 2:**

I have modified and re-asked my question [How to automate an update of a server copy of my remote repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228194/how-to-automate-an-update-of-a-server-copy-of-my-remote-repo)

Comment: AFAIK SourceTree is only a local Git client; the operations you would perform remotely would happen remotely, not with SourceTree.  I also think in general it would not be desirable to allow a local Git client to execute such operations.

Comment: Make a local repository. Do `git fetch` and `git merge` in this repository with SourceTree. Push the changes to update the remote repository.

Comment: SourceTree is the Git Client software where you can Checkout remote repository on your local machine and commit the changes locally. After you finished, you can Push the changes from Local repository to remote repository in the same branch. I don't think there is any way to perform these operations on remote branch using SourceTree.

Comment: Thank you everybody. I see where I'm wrong when I think about the process. I have updated my question. How to automate an update of a server copy of my remote repo?

Answer (score 1):

As the other question you asked, the direct answer is NO.

Since bitbucket remote repo is a bare repo (no working directory), so you should pull and merge from local repo by client hooks (such as pre-push hook), and then also push the merge commit into remote by `git push --all` to instead `git push origin foo-branch`.